# Custom iOS Tweet Sheet

Tags: ios, twitter, custom-controls

I am looking to have a custom looking tweet sheet to use in my application.

Obviously I can build my own and use the twitter API for posting; however, this would SEEM (Maybe its not THAT MUCH work, I can't say) to take a lot of work to build, especially in features like autocomplete for user twitter followers etc.

Is there anyway to customize the tweet sheet used by Apple's frameworks? It just looks god awful, especially compared to the design of my app.

If not, where can I look to implement the displaying friend results while typing in @user?

Any thoughts, idea's, links, suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Social.framework for signing your requests with data from accounts, which is in system.

Second step - make your own view for tweeting.

Third - get ACAccount. 
Like this:

```
ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountTypeTwitter = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountTypeTwitter options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                     if(granted) {
                                         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                             NSArray *accounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeTwitter];

                                             //All twitter accounts are in array, show sheet to select one of them.
                                         });
                                     }
                                 }];
```

Fourth - send SLRequest to twitter for post.

Example of SLRequest (to get information about user):

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=%@",account.username]];

        SLRequest *req = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:url parameters:nil];
        [req setAccount:account];
        [req performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *respData, NSHTTPURLResponse *resp, NSError *err){
//Req finished
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a head start for your own custom tweet sheet:
https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController